# What does "at the headline level" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "in theory"?

"While population growth of about 1.5 percent has helped underpin the economy’s expansion for 26 years, that’s only **at the headline level**. Drilling down, the economy expanded just 0.2 percent on a per capita basis in the year through the first quarter."

Source: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-07-12/australians-are-divided-over-their-economy-like-never-before

Answer (score 3):

## It means "in summary"

When writing headlines, you take the key points and summarise and condense them down, but stopping (we hope!) short of being misleading. The author is implying that this is the level of information conveyed in the first statement: it's roughly correct, but it's an overly condensed summary of a complex situation.

This is not a common idiom, at least not in my experience. (For the record, I'm Australian, but while the article is *about* my country, it's from an American source, so maybe it's more common in American English and I just haven't been exposed to it.)

Comment: +1 for "overly condensed summary of a complex situation".  "at the headline level" is just the author's metaphor -- not an idiom in AmE either.  Given the context, it is intended to mean "as seen over the long term", so the (not very clear) analogy is *headline font: long term :: normal-font : short-term*.